# Is there a way to perform static code analysis/linting for Angular memory leak?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

Let's say the proper pattern in Angular to unsubscribe from an observable in a component is thus:

[image: Canonical subscribe/unsubscribe]

Now let's say I forgot the .unsubscribe() call in ngOnDestroy(). Is there any linting rule I could set up to catch this, or it must strictly rely on code review?

Comment: from my experience, it's rely on code review. We tried to determine if there were memory leaks by using some chrome tool to look at active memory usage, but it wasn't anything fancy to track down what causing a leak. I forget what the tool was.

Comment: That's what I thought, there is no magic bullet.

Answer (score 0):

You could limit your code to the following specific pattern to clear the subscription, i.e.

```js
const e = a.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe();
```

Then you can use the `@angular-extensions/lint-rules` package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-extensions/lint-rules

by installing it with

```
npm install @angular-extensions/lint-rules --save-dev
```

and adding the following extension to your `tslint.json`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "@angular-extensions/lint-rules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That approach doesn't work for long lived Observable.

Comment: @Alex.A it can handle the same situations as the `.unsubscribe()` inside `ngOnDestroy()` approach. if the observable subscription should live longer than the component, it will be difficult to analyze statically